# How to define a column vector command using foreach and bmatrix?

Tags: line-breaking, matrices, columns, foreach

I am trying to do something like this,

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\col}[1]{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \foreach \i in {#1} {\i \\}
  \end{bmatrix}
}
```

Which unfortunately does not work, while this works,

```latex
\DeclareRobustCommand{\col}[1]{
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \foreach \i in {#1} {\i, }
  \end{bmatrix}
}
```

Could someone suggest a fix? I tried looking up this issue but am having a hard time understanding any of the answers.

Comment: Please provide a use case, i.e., an example of how `\col` might get called.

Comment: Like this, `\col{0, 1}` to write `\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}`. Which is a column vector.

Comment: Your `\foreach` will have issues with grouping, as each cell in an alignment forms an implicit group your `\foreach` starts in one group and should end in another, which doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to use `\\` between each element of a comma separated list you can use `\clist_use:nn` instead of temporary assignments to some other variable.

`\clist_use:nn` works by expansion only and has no issues with groups.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \col { m }
  {
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \clist_use:nn {#1} { \\ }
    \end{bmatrix}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  \col{1,4} + \col{2, 1} = \col{3,5}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what this does, but this works,

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\col}{m} {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_seq { ##1 }
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { \\ }
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Comment: This assigns your input data to a sequence variable, it then runs an inline function on each element of the sequence `tmpa` and stores the result in `tmpb` (that does nothing but copy in this case, as your incline function only forwards the input), it then inputs the contents of said sequence separated by `\\ `, filling your `bmatrix`. You can remove the `\seq_set_map:NNn` line and then inside `bmatrix` replace `tmpb` by `tmpa`.